# Google ControlWrapper for CategoryFilter

Tags: google-visualization

I have a `CategoryFilter` with a list of numbers, correctly ordered in the linked `DataTable`, but they are ordered like string value in the picker object. I.e.: 1,10,2,3 instead of 1,2,3,10. This is my code:

```js
var subdivPicker_1 = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
    'containerId': 'control3',
    'options':{
        'filterColumnIndex': 2,
        'ui': {
            'caption': 'Select month...',
            'label': 'Month',
            'labelStacking': 'vertical',
            'allowTyping': false,
            'allowMultiple': false
         }
    }
});
```

The `ColumnIndex` #2 contanins the month's number (1...12).

Also is there a way to order the months with the name? Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr....

Answer (score 0):

The CategoryFilter treats all data as strings, so there is no way to avoid lexicographic sorting.  You can turn off sorting and use the order the data appears in your DataTable by setting the `ui.sortValues` option to `false`.  If you want to use the names for the months, instead of the numbers, you can set the formatted values of the "Month" column cells to the names, and set the `useFormattedValue` option to `true`.

Comment: Hi, I have set the sortValues as suggested and works beacause it take into account the sort in the DataTable, but if I replace the number with months name setting useFormattedValue = false, it does not work and I get APR, AUG, DEC and so on...

Comment: Here is the code:

var columnChart2  = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    'chartType': 'ColumnChart',
    'containerId': 'chart4',
  'useFormattedValue': false,
  'options': {'legend': 'none', title: 'Month', 'chartArea': {left:60,top:20,width:"80%",height:"70%"}, 'bar': {groupWidth: '10'}},
    'dataTable' : google.visualization.data.group(data, [1],
    [{'column': 3, 'aggregation': google.visualization.data.sum, 'type': 'number'}])
});

Comment: ..and this is the data:

var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'State');
        data.addColumn('string', 'Year');
        data.addColumn('string', 'Month');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Amount');
        data.addRows([
    ['OPEN', '2011', 'JAN', 5011],
    ['CLOSE', '2011', 'JAN', 850],
    ['OPEN', '2011', 'FEB', 4059],
    ['CLOSE', '2011', 'FEB', 780],
    ['OPEN', '2011', 'MAR', 4138],
    ['CLOSE', '2011', 'MAR', 707],
    ['OPEN', '2011', 'APR', 3998],
    ['CLOSE', '2011', 'APR', 792]
        ]);